# Pyspark: pushing filter by date against apache phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-phoenix

I am trying to filter by date in apache phoenix from pyspark. The column in phoenix is created as Date and the filter is a datetime. When I use explain I see spark doesn't push the filter to phoenix. I have tried a lot of combinations without luck.

Any way to do it?

```
df = sqlContext.read \
   .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
  .option("table", "TABLENAME") \
  .option("zkUrl",zookepperServer +":2181:/hbase-unsecure" ) \
  .load()
print(df.printSchema())

startValidation = datetime.datetime.now()

print(df.filter(df['FH'] >startValidation).explain(True))
```

Results

```
root
 |-- METER_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FH: date (nullable = true)

None
   == Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter (FH#53 > 1486726683446150)
+- Relation[METER_ID#52,FH#53,SUMMERTIME#54,MAGNITUDE#55,SOURCE#56,ENTRY_DATETIME#57,BC#58,T_VAL_AE#59,T_VAL_AI#60,T_VAL_R1#61,T_VAL_R2#62,T_VAL_R3#63,T_VAL_R4#64] PhoenixRelation(DAILYREADS,10.0.0.13:2181:/hbase-unsecure)

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
METER_ID: string, FH: date, SUMMERTIME: string, MAGNITUDE: int, SOURCE: int, ENTRY_DATETIME: date, BC: string, T_VAL_AE: int, T_VAL_AI: int, T_VAL_R1: int, T_VAL_R2: int, T_VAL_R3: int, T_VAL_R4: int
Filter (cast(FH#53 as string) > cast(1486726683446150 as string))
+- Relation[METER_ID#52,FH#53,SUMMERTIME#54,MAGNITUDE#55,SOURCE#56,ENTRY_DATETIME#57,BC#58,T_VAL_AE#59,T_VAL_AI#60,T_VAL_R1#61,T_VAL_R2#62,T_VAL_R3#63,T_VAL_R4#64] PhoenixRelation(DAILYREADS,10.0.0.13:2181:/hbase-unsecure)

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (cast(FH#53 as string) > 2017-02-10 11:38:03.44615)
+- Relation[METER_ID#52,FH#53,SUMMERTIME#54,MAGNITUDE#55,SOURCE#56,ENTRY_DATETIME#57,BC#58,T_VAL_AE#59,T_VAL_AI#60,T_VAL_R1#61,T_VAL_R2#62,T_VAL_R3#63,T_VAL_R4#64] PhoenixRelation(DAILYREADS,10.0.0.13:2181:/hbase-unsecure)

== Physical Plan ==
Filter (cast(FH#53 as string) > 2017-02-10 11:38:03.44615)
+- Scan PhoenixRelation(DAILYREADS,10.0.0.13:2181:/hbase-unsecure)[METER_ID#52,FH#53,SUMMERTIME#54,MAGNITUDE#55,SOURCE#56,ENTRY_DATETIME#57,BC#58,T_VAL_AE#59,T_VAL_AI#60,T_VAL_R1#61,T_VAL_R2#62,T_VAL_R3#63,T_VAL_R4#64]
None
```

if I set the FH column as timestamp it pushes the filter but throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 604 (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting "RPAREN", got "12" at line 1, column 219.
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1280)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1363)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.compileQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1373)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.optimizeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1368)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:122)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: MismatchedTokenException(106!=129)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.recoverFromMismatchedToken(PhoenixSQLParser.java:360)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.not_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:6862)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.and_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:6677)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.or_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:6614)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:6579)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.single_select(PhoenixSQLParser.java:4615)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.unioned_selects(PhoenixSQLParser.java:4697)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.select_node(PhoenixSQLParser.java:4763)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:789)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:508)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
    ... 107 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically questions are asked on Apache dev lists and issues are reported in JIRA. Your JIRA was kindly responded to (within 4 hours) here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3664?focusedCommentId=15863720&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15863720

Not a big fan of the shotgun approach of tweeting + stack overflow + dev list + JIRA. Please keep in mind that the folks that respond all have day jobs.

Comment: Sorry again for the shotgun. I didn't know where to ask and tried in different places. Next time only Jira.

Thanks!